# Azure Logic Apps: Check for file type

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I setup an Azure Logic App that checks for newly created files in a OneDrive folder and then sends these (images) to the MS Vision API for tagging. This flow works fine.

How can I setup a condition to only react on a specific file type (images) or even better only when the file has a certain file ending, like ".jpg", ".png" etc.?

I tried to setup a condition on the "File content type" but couldn't figure out the appropriate value for the condition ("image" doesn't work).

[image]

I couldn't find any hints on the webs and neither on SO. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading file attachments using the GMail action, I had to use `starts with` because the Content-Type property contained the MIME type followed by the file name.

The following example is for checking if the file is an Excel file (.xlsx, ***not*** .xls):

[image]

I also used http://mime.ritey.com/ to upload my files and ensure I had the MIME type correct.

Answer (score 1):

**File name** is part of the metadata provided by the OneDrive Connector.

Using that, you can apply conditions/filters based on the extension.  **File content type** is probably pretty reliable but in practice, the extension might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I was able to kind of reverse engineer the file types by setting up an app that is triggered by new files and writes the file content type to a text file in a different folder.

- `image/jpg` and `image/png` are image files
- `application/x-zip-compressed` is a zipped file

So it seems that Azure uses standard MIME types to identify the file type (which very much makes sense... :0)